# All section titles in one uniform color in friggeri Latex CV

Tags: pdftex, color, friggeri-cv

do you know how to change the colors of the section titles in the [friggeri](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv) 
cv?

I would like for them to be in one color and also the entire word, not only the first three letters.

Is there any solution to this?

thank you in advance

Comment: But the color stuff is all the template/style is about.

Comment: I know but for professional reason I would lile the headers to be uniformly in one color, e.g. blue. How is that posssible?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is controlled by `\@sectioncolor`, which was originally defined so that it'd colour the first three characters of the section title. Redefining it like this will make all letters of all section title the same colour (blue in this case):

```
\makeatletter
\def\@sectioncolor{\color{blue}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick hack: add the following redefinitions to your file (all to the same value of whatever colour you want in the headlines, e.g. to get all light blue)

```
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{6CE0F1}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{6CE0F1}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{6CE0F1}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{6CE0F1}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{6CE0F1}
\definecolor{brown}{HTML}{6CE0F1}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you ! I already tried that but I do want all the letters of the headers appearing in the same colour. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: maybe use one the grey as the colour `\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{333333}` ?

Answer (score 0):

The colour of the section title can be altered by changing the definition of the sectioncolor. I did too try to change the colour of the section heading but altering with the colors section resulted in additional unwanted change.

Hence the Structure sectioncan be altered. You would notice the `def\@sectioncolor` under the newcounter. altering the parameters to `#1#2#3#4#5#6#7` would do the job too provided all your section headers are of the same length. Keep adding hash characters till the length of the string that is but do note that the strings shorter than the highest hash number will not be displayed.

Ultimately the best solution is:

```
\RequirePackage{parskip}
\newcounter{colorCounter}
\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
  {%
    \color{%
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        pblue\or%
        pblue\or%
        pblue\or%
        pblue\or%
        pblue\else%
        pblue\fi%
    } #1#2#3%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
  {%
    \LARGE\headingfont\color{***pblue}***%            
    \@sectioncolor #1%
  }
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[2]{
  \par\vspace{.5\parskip}%
  \Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} #2%
  \par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
}

\pagestyle{empty}
```

Note here the bold and italic "pblue" is the colour you want your section header to be.